# Select2 has-error Bootstrap class not working (with AngularJS Validation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2-4

I googled it but I'm getting answers based on jQuery validation. Hoping I can get answer from here.

I have the same ng-class in my other forms and they seem to be working fine with has-error class. The label is being affected by the has-error class but not the select2.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-sm-12" ng-class="gdForm.$submitted && gdForm.company.$error.required ? 'has-error' : ''">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Company</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <select ng-model="formData.company.company_id" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" required>
      <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled"></option>
      <option ng-repeat="company in companies | orderBy: 'company_name'" value="{{ company.company_id }}">{{ company.company_name }}</option>
    </select>
     <span class="help-block small"
        ng-show="gdForm.$submitted && gdForm.company.$error.required">
         <i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Company is required.
     </span>
  </div>
</div>
```